# Migrating SVN Repository authentication store and logins

Tags: svn, authentication

My company is changing user name scheme and authentication store at the same time:

Currently: LDAP with login:
firstname.lastname

In the future: AD with login:
firlas (first 3 letters of first name and first 3 letters of last name) 
but preserving firstname.lastname@example.com for e-mail address.

We have 2 separate repositories affected by this, each about few dozen users and many thousands of revisions.

We use HTTP to access SVN.

How to best approach this?

We used to take the user name and use it in a lot of scripts post/pre commit to send e-mail looking it up in LDAP etc. It would be best if we could keep using firstname.lastname in SVN.

Thank you in advance.